# Filter javascript array of objects on condition

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a scenario where I need to filter the array based on the elements present in another object.

Eg:

```
x = [{ id:1, name: test},{id:2, name:test1},{id:3, name:test3}]
conditionObj = {test:true, test1:false, test3: false};
```

my Result should be 
   x = [{id:1, name:test}]

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```
x.filter(elem => conditionObj[elem.name]])
```

Use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the array and do a lookup in `conditionObj`.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const newObj = x.filter(val => {
    return conditionObj[val.name];
})
```